# How to add customizable alphabet and rotation to a ROT13 algorithm?

Tags: python, encryption

I have made a code to encrypt messages using the regular ROT13 system, but my teacher wanted me to make it so that the user could add a custom alphabet and custom rotation.
He also wanted me to use dictionaries for this, but I have no clue how to do this. He told me to leave it be, but i am really curious as to how to do this.

This is the code I wrote to start with.

```py
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"


def encrypt(text):
    text = text.lower()

    result = ""

    for char in text:
        if char.isalpha():
            result += alphabet[(alphabet.index(char) + 13) % 26]
        else:
            result += char
    return result


def decrypt(text):
    text = text.lower()

    result = ""

    for char in text:
        if char.isalpha():
            position = alphabet.index(char) - 13
            if position < 0:
                result += alphabet[26 + position]
            else:
                result += alphabet[position]
        else:
            result += char
    return result


answer = input("\n do you want to Encrypt or Decrypt? [E/D]\n")
answer = answer.upper()

if answer == "E":
    encrypt_msg = input("\nWhat do you wnat to ENcrypt?\n")
    result = encrypt(encrypt_msg)
elif answer == "D":
    decrypt_msg = input("\nWhat do you want to DEcrypt?\n")
    result = decrypt(decrypt_msg)

print(f"\nthis is you finished message:  {result}\n")
```

Comment: Can you ask your teacher why you might need a dictionary for this? Have you considered asking your user to input an alphabet and a rotation value?

Answer (score 0):

`argparse` is a Python module allowing you to pass arguments to a Python script : https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

You could add a string parameter for the alphabet (defaulting to the one you defined as in the first line of your file), and an integer parameter for the rotation (defaulting to whatever you think is best for a "standard" value).

Here would be an example:

```py
import argparse


def encrypt(text, rotation, alphabet):
    text = text.lower()

    result = ""

    for char in text:
        if char.isalpha():
            result += alphabet[(alphabet.index(char) + rotation) % len(alphabet)]
        else:
            result += char
    return result


def decrypt(text, rotation, alphabet):
    text = text.lower()

    result = ""

    for char in text:
        if char.isalpha():
            position = alphabet.index(char) - rotation
            if position < 0:
                result += alphabet[len(alphabet) + position]
            else:
                result += alphabet[position]
        else:
            result += char
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog="ProgramName",
        description="What the program does",
        epilog="Text at the bottom of help",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-r",
        "--rotation",
        dest="rotation",
        type=int,
        help="Rotation for the encryption",
        default=13,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-a",
        "--alphabet",
        dest="alphabet",
        default="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
        help="The alphabet you want to use",
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()

    answer = input("\n do you want to Encrypt or Decrypt? [E/D]\n")
    answer = answer.upper()

    if answer == "E":
        encrypt_msg = input("\nWhat do you wnat to ENcrypt?\n")
        result = encrypt(encrypt_msg, args.rotation, args.alphabet)
    elif answer == "D":
        decrypt_msg = input("\nWhat do you want to DEcrypt?\n")
        result = decrypt(decrypt_msg, args.rotation, args.alphabet)

    print(f"\nthis is your finished message:  {result}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between encoding and decoding in ROT13 (a.k.a. the Caesar cypher) is that the rotation value (ROT) is either added to or subtracted from the offset in the alphabet where the character being processed is found.

Thus we can simplify the whole process:

```
from operator import sub, add
from string import ascii_lowercase

ALPHABET = ascii_lowercase
ROT = 13

def common(s, op):
    r = []
    for c in s:
        if (i := ALPHABET.find(c)) >= 0:
            o = op(i, ROT) % len(ALPHABET)
            r.append(ALPHABET[o])
        else:
            r.append(c)
    return ''.join(r)

def encrypt(s):
    return common(s, add)

def decrypt(s):
    return common(s, sub)

if value := input('Enter your alphabet or enter/return to use default: '):
    ALPHABET = value

if value := input('Enter ROT or enter/return to use default: '):
    ROT = int(value)

value = input('Enter the string to be encrypted or decrypted: ')

action = input('Do you wish to [E]ncrypt or [D]ecrypt this value? ').upper()

if action == 'D':
    print(decrypt(value))
elif action == 'E':
    print(encrypt(value))
else:
    print(f'{value} is an invalid option')
```